# AngularJS - How to transclude into a script element?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

**[See Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Uzyaxqb8WuqJuU7Bbf1Y?p=preview)**

I would like to transclude the content of the directive element into a `<script>` element.

In the below directive, transclusion does not work when the template contains a script tag as in the following:

```
app.directive('mdl', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'EA'
        , replace: true
        , transclude: true
        , template: '<script id="modal.html" > <div ng-transclude> </div> </script>'
    }

})
```

where the directive is invoked as follows:

```
<mdlbody>  <div>testing modal body</div>  </mdlbody>
```

The resulting `<main>` element is empty. However, transclude works as expected when the `<script>` tag is removed from the template string like so,

```
template: '<div ng-transclude> </div>'
```

or `template: <div> <div ng-transclude> </div> <div>`

As long as the template string is not wrapped in `<script>` , the transclude works.
Transclude also works when ng-transclude is placed directly on `<script ng-transclude>`. However I want to insert the transclude at a deeper level of nesting inside the `<script>` element.

Why is this so? How can I get transclude to work with the `<script>` element in template string? (so that the directive's content is transcluded into the `<script>` element)

P.S: To clarify further, I am trying to transclude **into** the **script** element so the end result should be `<script><main> transcluded content</main></script>` 
(**not** `<main> transcluded content</main>`).

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to refer to a template for this directive then replace template with templateurl because template expects some html code with angular directives write this:

```
app.directive('mdl', function(){
return {
    restrict: 'EA'
    , replace: true
    , transclude: true
    , templateUrl: 'modal'
}

})
```

and place the below lines at the end of your .htm file

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="modal" > <main ng-transclude> </main> </script>
```

Comment: This does NOT accomplish the objective, which is to transclude into the <script> element.

Comment: please check i forgot the ng-transclude property...i have edited it

Comment: Please read the question again, I am trying to transclude INTO the SCRIPT element so the end result should be <script><main> transcluded content</main></script> ( NOT  <main> transcluded content</main> )I appreciate your looking into this, but your answer does not accomplish transclusion into the script element, even with the edit you just made.

Comment: I added the clarification to the question.